# Getting "Undefined" reading logicalDensityFactor on Android

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, appcelerator

I'm testing a Titanium App on an Android emulator.

I use dip units, so i need to know the Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor to get the propers numbers.
But when I try to read:

> - Ti.Platform.displayCaps.logicalDensityFactor
> - Ti.Platform.displayCaps.xdpi
> - Ti.Platform.displayCaps.ydpi

I get `undefined` everytime!

Someone knows why this happen to me? is the emulator or what?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution!
The string is Case Sensitive and Titanium don't generate any error if you write it wrong.
Another problem is that Titanium suggest me

```
Ti.Platform.DisplayCaps
```

and not with a lower "**D**"

```
Ti.Platform.displayCaps
```

So if you get this error, make sure that you had write correctly the string!

Comment: The reason you didn't get an error is because both of those calls exist in the API "The Display Caps object (Titanium.Platform.DisplayCaps) is returned by the Titanium.Platform.displayCaps property."